# WebAPI ActionName vs AttributeRouting

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Team,
       I started working on WebAPI and have come across a doubt while overloading the webAPI action i.e. we have -

```
[ActionName("GetValue")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Can the same overloading be done using AttributeRouting as below

```
[GET("GetValue"), HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

if not then when we have to use attributerouting. Any suggestion/help on this will be of great help.

Comment: By default it's a get. Put it through fiddler, you'll soon see if the attribute routing works as you switch between GET SET PUT DELETE etc :)

Comment: Appreciate your quick response the thing is I am aware of ActionName attribute but not when exactly to decorate using [GET("ActionName\{param}") attribute I have found in an existing webAPI and couldn't understand the purpose for action get as well as Post are decorated.